# Proof by Induction Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, induction

I am stuck on trying to prove this algorithm using mathematical induction.

```
add_list(s,n) {
//add a list s of numbers with length n
    sum = 0
    for i = 1 to n
        sum = sum + si
    return sum
```

I know I need to start with a base case, and I'm guessing that it would look something like this:

for n = 0, sum = 0 + 0.

I am not sure then how to proceed with setting up the inductive hypothesis and the rest of the proof though. help pls...

Comment: What do you mean by “proving an algorithm”?

Comment: I think this could be considered a part of mathematics. The question was: how do you prove/show that what an algorithm does is correct? This is an important topic in the theoretical analysis of algorithms - they use the same methods as in pure math. In particular, in this case an inductive proof was requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is, I think, to prove that the outlined algorithm computes $s(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n s_i$, for a 'list' $(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$.

Yes, your base case appears correct: if $n=0$, then the list is empty, so $\sum_{i=1}^n s_i=0$ (a bit by convention) and this algorithm, too, returns $0$.

Otherwise, let $n>0$. Assume that the algorithm correctly computes $s({m})$ for all lists of length $m=n-1$. Rewrite your above loop as

`for i=1 to n-1
   sum = sum + s[i]
 sum = sum + s[n]`

You see that the first part is add_list(t,n-1) where $t$ is the list $(s_1,\ldots,s_{n-1})$, which, by assumption, correctly returns $s({n-1})$. Then your algorithm outputs $s({n-1})+s_n$, which, obviously, equals $s(n)$.

Comment: Nice explanation, though I don't care for the notation $s^n$ since it is suggestive of raising a number $s$ to the $n$.

Comment: Agreed. I edited it.